# Excel VBA code to transpose data from rows to columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in column A with 50000 rows of data. I need to transpose every 6 rows of data to 6 columns. For example data from A1:A6 must be transposed to B1:G1. Again data from A7:A14 must be transposed to B2:G2. I appreciate if anyone can provide VBA code for this.

> Data I have in column A is as shown below:

```
Col A
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

> The transpose data must be as shown below in col B to col G:

```
Columns  B   C   D   E   F   G
         1   2   3   4   5   6
         7   8   9   10  11  12
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

additional variant from my side:

```
Sub TransposeRows2()
    Dim i&, z&, x&
    i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    z = 1: x = 1
    While z <= i
        Range("B" & x).Resize(, 6) = _
            WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A" & z).Resize(6))
        z = z + 6: x = x + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

tested:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
Sub TransposeRows()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = Range("A1")
    While rng.Value <> ""
        i = i + 1
        rng.Resize(6).Copy
        Range("B" & i).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        Set rng = rng.Offset(6)            
    Wend
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Got this from [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/231462-visual-basic-applications-automatically-transpose-x-rows-data-into-columns.html).

Answer (score 7):

You do not need a macro for this.  In **B1** enter:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,COLUMNS($A:A)-1+(ROWS($1:1)-1)*6,0)
```

Then copy both across and down:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but if dragged/copied it duplicates to all cells.

Answer (score 0):

In Portuguese Excel, "Gary's Student"'s formula, for 4 columns instead of 6, becomes:

```
=DESLOCAMENTO($A$1;COLS($A:A)-1+(LINS($1:1)-1)*4;0)
```