# Copying Cells from other workbooks into one workbook automatically

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have many excel files of the same structure in one folder (Sample 1, Sample 2......Sample 20). I created another excel file in the same folder that needs to pull out information from each other excel file (Results). There is a specific column in each Sample file that I need to copy and paste into a row in the Results file. I am trying to create a tool or Macro that can, from a push of a button, extract the same column from each file and paste it into a new row in the Results file. I cannot alter anything in the Sample files and this should be done automatically without opening each file.  Also new Sample files will be added to the folder (Sample 21...22 etc) so the function should be able to pull from the new files.

Edit.

Based off of Pomul's suggestion of transposing the rows. I came up with the following code and results.  Right now I am testing the code to transpose in the same worksheet:

#### Transpose Image Screenshot

[image: Transpose Image Screenshot]

Please let me know why my code makes another column instead of transposing it into a row.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work:

```
Sub Button1_click()
Dim i&, z&, x&

i = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
z = 1: x = 1

While z <= i
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x).Resize(, i) = _
        WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & z).Resize(i))
    z = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Pomul,

Your function helps to copy that specific cell to my cell.  Do you know of a way to copy lets say (Column D3:D15 from Sample1.xlsx) and paste it in (Row B2:N2 from results.xlsx)?

Comment: @Ridwan - Have you tried the Transpose function?https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027

Comment: @Ridwan this question is very similar to yours, chances are you can modify the macro to fit your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545372/excel-macro-to-transpose-data-from-rows-to-columns

Comment: I need it to transpose to a different workbook, would I still use the same procedure?

Comment: Give it a test run and see if it works! Formulas can link to different workbooks, i don't why this one wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi Pomul, Please see the description. I added a snapshot of an issue I am running into using the transposing function. Right now I am testing it on a single workbook.

Comment: @Ridwan - I modified the orignial answer as the comments was not an apporpriate place to put the new code. Additionnaly, in your question, you are asking about linking to multiple files, here is a code for you to tweak: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg549168(v=office.14).aspx