# Excel 2016 VBA - Add cell in front of transposed data

Tags: vba, excel

I have reused the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545372/excel-vba-code-to-transpose-data-from-rows-to-columns) and added some code

```
Sub TransposeRows2()
Dim i&, z&, x&
i = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
z = 1: x = 1
While z <= i
    ' Added code
    Range("A" & z).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J" & x).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ' Added code end
    Range("K" & x).Resize(, 7) = _
        WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("D" & z).Resize(7))
    z = z + 7: x = x + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

To each transposed row I want to add a cell to the left. But doing this with the below code slows down the action (there is more than 300.000 rows).

```
Range("A" & z).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J" & x).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Is there another way to add a cell to the left of each transposed row?

**Original data**

```
Jumphost    Application License Key xxx-xxx
Jumphost    Application License Type    Std.
Jumphost    Application Product ID  xxx-xxx
Jumphost    Application Display Name    Juniper Networks  Inc.
Jumphost    Application Installation Date   20-10-2014
Jumphost    Application Publisher   Juniper Networks, Inc.
Jumphost    Application Version 2.1.1.1
```

**Transposed data**

```
Jumphost    xxx-xxx Std.    xxx-xxx Juniper Networks  Inc.  20-10-2014  Juniper Networks, Inc.  2.1.1.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a duplicate of column J to the left of the transposed row

If so (and for 300,000 rows) I'd suggest using an array to transpose and copy all data:

```
Rows: 302,407; Time: 6.320 sec
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TransposeRows1()     'Fast (array)

    Const SR = 2    'Start row

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, arr As Variant, r1 As Long, r2 As Long, tr As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    arr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(SR, "A"), ws.Cells(lr, "R")).Formula    'Copy Range to Array

    tr = 1
    For r1 = 1 To lr Step 7
        If r1 < lr - 7 Then
            arr(tr, 10) = arr(r1, 1) 'Col J (If empty replace arr(r1, 1) with vbNullString
            arr(tr, 11) = arr(r1, 1) 'Col K
            For r2 = 0 To 6
                arr(tr, 12 + r2) = arr(r1 + r2, 4)  'Col M to R
            Next r2
            tr = tr + 1     'Next transposed row
        End If
    Next r1
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(SR, "A"), ws.Cells(lr, "R")).Formula = arr    'Paste Array to Range
End Sub
```

---

Result

[image: Result]

---

.

To fix your code:

**V1** - Copy / Paste column J at the end, or simply insert an empty column  before J

```
Rows: 302,407; Time: 43.516 sec
```

---

```
Public Sub TransposeRows2()     'copy/paste J col at the end
 Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, c As Long, t As Long

 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
 c = 2
 t = 2
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 While c <= lr
  ws.Range("A" & c).Copy ws.Range("J" & t)
  ws.Range("K" & t).Resize(, 7) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("D" & c).Resize(7))
  c = c + 7
  t = t + 1
 Wend
 With ws.UsedRange
    .Columns("J").Copy
    .Columns("K").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
 End With
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**V2** - Insert J cells while iterating

```
Rows: 302,407; Time: 42.883 sec
```

---

```
Public Sub TransposeRows3()     'insert J cell while looping
 Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, c As Long, t As Long

 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
 c = 2
 t = 2
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 While c <= lr
  ws.Range("A" & c).Copy ws.Range("J" & t & ":K" & t)
  ws.Range("L" & t).Resize(, 7) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("D" & c).Resize(7))
  c = c + 7
  t = t + 1
 Wend
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with your array code. Speedy solution